# Getting null pointer on ActionView item

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

I get null pointer when I try to refer the actionView in drawer menu item. I need to refer view `nl.dionsegijn.steppertouch.StepperTouch` (defined in `locaton_item_layout.xml`) in my `MainActivity.java` file. I'm trying to run following code to do so. Now, the value returned for variable `actionViewLayout` is null. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Please help.

Here's my `MainActivity.java` file:

```
...
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu);
        LinearLayout actionViewLayout = (LinearLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.item_with_action).getActionView();
        stepperTouch = (StepperTouch) actionViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.stepperTouch);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
...
```

Here's `activity_main_drawer.xml` file:

```
...
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_with_action"
        android:title="Show Results for"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/location_item_layout">
        app:showAsAction="always"
    </item>
...
```

Here's `location_item_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/actionviewlayout">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Now+"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <nl.dionsegijn.steppertouch.StepperTouch
        android:id="@+id/stepperTouch"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp">
    </nl.dionsegijn.steppertouch.StepperTouch>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the menu item in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. You should only initialize the menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu):

> After the system calls onCreateOptionsMenu(), it retains an instance
>   of the Menu you populate and will not call onCreateOptionsMenu() again
>   unless the menu is invalidated for some reason. However, **you should use onCreateOptionsMenu() only to create the initial menu state and
>   not to make changes during the activity lifecycle.**
>
> If you want to modify the options menu based on events that occur
>   during the activity lifecycle, you can do so in the
>   onPrepareOptionsMenu() method. This method passes you the Menu object
>   as it currently exists so you can modify it, such as add, remove, or
>   disable items. (Fragments also provide an onPrepareOptionsMenu()
>   callback.)

So, you need to move your code to `onPerepareOptionsMenu()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  LinearLayout actionViewLayout = (LinearLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.item_with_action).getActionView();
  stepperTouch = (StepperTouch) actionViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.stepperTouch);

  return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I tried as you suggested, but I'm still getting the exact same error.